# What exactly does the 'Base Collect Tracking Code' in Personalization Builder refer to?

Tags: marketing-cloud, collection, einstein-recommendations

I've been looking through all the documentation, and I can't seem to identify what the 'Base Collect Tracking Code' is referring to, or why it is now 0 for us.  It used to have data in it as far as I can remember, but it no longer does and I'm trying to decide if I should be concerned.  The 'track category views' we don't use, but what information are we missing by not having any data in Base Collect Tracking?

[image: Screenshot of our Status page]

Answer (score 7):

The Base collect code is just the collect.js, this script does not collect any information. All information that is tracked is gather by the track calls.

There is also a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KPMeQAO) for this behavior

Comment: Thanks for the response!